# Add product to cart not working on configurable product after enabling MSI (Multi Source Inventory) Magento2

Tags: magento2.3.4, multi-source-inventory, pwa-theme

**Not able to add configurable product to cart after I have enable the msi:**

**It is showing error from graphql api:**

> Product that you are trying to add is not available.

[image: error]

Comment: Try to reindex Inventory index

Comment: After enabling MSI do you have assigned any source/stock to that configurable product. Check salable quantity in the backend.

Comment: yes i have assign two sources to product its salable is ok but not able to add product to cart